# Normalizing matrix row scipy matrix

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I wish to normalize each row of a sparse scipy matrix, obtained from a networkx directed graph.

```
 import networkx as nx
 import numpy as np

G=nx.random_geometric_graph(10,0.3)
M=nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G, nodelist=G.nodes())

from __future__ import division

 print(M[3])
  (0, 1)        1
  (0, 5)        1

print(M[3].multiply(1/M[3].sum()))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  (0, 1)        0.5
  (0, 5)        0.5
```

this is ok, I normalize as usual and it's working as desired.
But if I write:

```
>>> M[3]=M[3].multiply(1/M[3].sum())
>>> M[3]
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
  (0, 0)        0
  (0, 1)        0
  (0, 2)        0
  (0, 3)        0
  (0, 4)        0
  (0, 5)        0
  (0, 6)        0
  (0, 7)        0
  (0, 8)        0
  (0, 9)        0
```

I just need to iterate over each row and normalize over this sparse scipy matrix. 
How would you do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it (from networkx.pagerank_scipy).  It uses scipy linear algebra functions instead of iterating over each row.  That will probably be faster for large graphs.

```
In [42]: G=nx.random_geometric_graph(5,0.5)

In [43]: M=nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G, nodelist=G.nodes(), dtype=float)

In [44]: M.todense()
Out[44]: 
matrix([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.]])

In [45]: S = scipy.array(M.sum(axis=1)).flatten()

In [46]: S[S != 0] = 1.0 / S[S != 0]

In [47]: Q = scipy.sparse.spdiags(S.T, 0, *M.shape, format='csr')

In [48]: (Q*M).todense()
Out[48]: 
matrix([[ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.33333333],
        [ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.5       ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ],
        [ 0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.33333333],
        [ 0.25      ,  0.25      ,  0.25      ,  0.25      ,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why

```
print(M[3].multiply(1/M[3].sum()))
```

produces expected results, and

```
M[3]=M[3].multiply(1/M[3].sum())
```

produces zeros is because `M` is an integer array, `<type 'numpy.int64'>`.  As long as we don't try to assign the norm back to `M` this isn't a problem.

If `M.A`

```
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

the sum over columns is: `Msum = M.sum(axis=1)`.  It is dense

```
matrix([[3],
        [2],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]], dtype=int32)
```

as is its inverse:

```
Mnorm = 1/Msum
matrix([[ 0.33333333],
        [ 0.5       ],
        [ 0.5       ],
        [ 0.33333333],
        [ 0.25      ]])
```

`M.multiply(Mnorm)` is dense  (just the way `M.multiply` is setup).  But make the norm sparse, and the product is also sparse

```
M1 = M.multiply(sparse.csr_matrix(Mnorm))
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 14 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
M1.A
array([[ 0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.25      ,  0.25      ,  0.25      ,  0.25      ,  0.        ]])
```

The equivalent dense `numpy` operation is:

```
A = M.A
A/np.sum(A, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```