# Normalize sparse row probability matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I've got a sparse matrix with a few elements. Now I would like to row normalize it. However, when I do this, it gets converted to a numpy array, which is not acceptable from a performance standpoint.

To make things more concrete, consider the following example:

```
x = csr_matrix([[0, 1, 1], [2, 3, 0]])  # sparse
normalization = x.sum(axis=1)  # dense, this is OK

x / normalization  # this is dense, not OK, can be huge
```

Is there an elegant way to do this without having to resort to for loops?

**EDIT**

Yes, this can be done using `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` using 'l1' normalization, however, I have no wish to depend on sklearn.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305021/efficient-way-to-normalize-a-scipy-sparse-matrix

Comment: ... and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260642/normalizing-matrix-row-scipy-matrix

Comment: I have no wish to depend on either scikit learn or networkx. This is not very helpful.

Comment: *"I have no wish to depend on either scikit learn or networkx."* Well, if you put that in the question, then we would *know* that those suggestions are not helpful.  We can't read your mind!

Comment: You're right, I should've made that explicit.

Comment: The second answer in the suggested duplicate by 0x01 shows how to do it without scikit-learn.  Also, the second answer in the second suggested duplicate by Warren Weckesser.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, however it is done using nested for loops, something I did make explicit that I don't want to do. My question is simply whether there is an elegant solution for this using numpy or scipy to get the nice speed benefits of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use `csr` internals:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> 
>>> x = sparse.csr_matrix([[0, 1, 1], [2, 3, 0]]) 
>>> 
>>> x.data = x.data / np.repeat(np.add.reduceat(x.data, x.indptr[:-1]), np.diff(x.indptr))
>>> x
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> x.A
array([[0. , 0.5, 0.5],
       [0.4, 0.6, 0. ]])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is good to know. Thanks. +1.

Comment: On a 1000x800 random matrix, your answer is faster than even the `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`.